# 1. How to fix cpanel errors. 2. Missing mysql 3. Facing 500 error codes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am faced with issues setting up my website on hostinger server platform. I need help to fix my cpanel errors

I installed WordPress through hostinger softaculous app installer, but I get a result saying (your php installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.)

When I tried using cpanel I get error code 500

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix your issue by editing your existing PHP installation upgrading to the latest PHP version and making sure the MySQL extension is installed and enabled.

See this tutorial for a quick guide for more information: https://jetpack.com/blog/php-installation-missing-mysql-extension/

I'm not a fan of Softaculous, but I'm not here to bash anyone's hard work. From experience, you're much better at installing WordPress yourself following the default WordPress installation processes.